# Can I pass the same mutable trait object in multiple iterations of a loop without adding indirection?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a bit of code that can either output to stdout or to a file. Based on some external condition, I instantiate the file or stdout and then create a trait object from the reference to the appropriate item:

```
use std::{io,fs};

fn write_it<W>(mut w: W) where W: io::Write { }

fn main() {
    let mut stdout;
    let mut file;

    let t: &mut io::Write = if true {
        stdout = io::stdout();
        &mut stdout
    } else {
        file = fs::File::create("/tmp/output").unwrap();
        &mut file
    };

    for _ in 0..10 {
        write_it(t);
    }
}
```

This works fine, until I try to call `write_it` multiple times. That will fail, as `t` is moved into `write_it` and thus is not available on subsequent iterations of the loop:

```
<anon>:18:18: 18:19 error: use of moved value: `t`
<anon>:18         write_it(t);
                           ^
note: `t` was previously moved here because it has type `&mut std::io::Write`, which is non-copyable
```

I can work around it by adding another layer of indirection:

```
let mut t: &mut io::Write;
write_it(&mut t);
```

But this seems like it could be potentially inefficient. Is it actually inefficient? Is there a cleaner way of writing this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly reborrow:

```rust
for _ in 0..10 {
    write_it(&mut *t);
}
```

One often sees this happen implicitly, but it is not in this case because `write_it` takes a raw generic, `W`, and the compiler only implicitly reborrows a `&mut` when used in a place that is expecting a `&mut`. E.g. if it was

```rust
fn write_it<W: ?Sized + Write>(w: &mut W) { ... }
```

your code works fine, since explicit `&mut` in the type of the argument will ensure that the compiler will implicitly reborrow with a shorter lifetime (i.e. the `&mut*`).

Cases like this demonstrate that `&mut` does in fact move ownership, the implicit reborrowing often disguises it in favour of improved ergonomics.

As for performance of the version with the extra reference: the speed of a `&mut (&mut Write)` is likely to be indistinguishable from a plain `&mut Write`: the virtual call will usually be much more expensive than dereferencing the `&mut`.

Furthermore, the aliasing guarantees of `&mut` means the compiler is very free about how interacts with a `&mut`: e.g., depending on the internals, it may load the two words of the `&mut Write` from the pointer into registers once at the start of `write_it` and then write any changes back at the end. This is legal because being a `&mut` means that there's nothing else that can mutate that memory.

Lastly, at the moment, a "large" value like a `&mut Write` is passed via a pointer; essentially the same as a `&mut &mut Write` on the machine. The assembly for both the `&mut *t` and `&mut t` versions both start (literally the only difference I can see is the names of the `Ltmp...` labels):

```asm
_ZN8write_it20h2919620193267806634E:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmpq    %fs:112, %rsp
    ja  .LBB4_2
    movabsq $72, %r10
    movabsq $0, %r11
    callq   __morestack
    retq
.LBB4_2:
    pushq   %r14
.Ltmp116:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp117:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    subq    $56, %rsp
.Ltmp118:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 80
.Ltmp119:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
.Ltmp120:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -16
    movq    (%rdi), %rsi
    movq    8(%rdi), %rax
    ...
```

The two `movq`s at the end are loading the two words of the `&mut Write` trait object into registers.

Comment: I thought about going the `?Sized` route — do you think that would be better than reborrowing?

Comment: If you don't wish to transfer ownership then taking `&mut` probably makes more sense.

Comment: What about just using .by_ref() when you call it to reborrow? Using by-value Write is more convenient with a number of writers, for example an adapted writer.